# Disable animation on tabs click android bottom bar navigation - roughike

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-bottomnav

I'm using roughike library for bottom bar navigation in my android project. But facing a problem that is when I click on the tabs it's getting bigger. I tried many ways to disable the animation but unable to do it. I asked on the github support page but no luck. I just took a look at the source code and found there is a fix property which causing the problem and there may no functions to edit this. Someone please help me if there is any way to disable the animation.

Note: I'm using all default settings from the github readme. But I tried changing options etc.

Thanks,
Robin

https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Comment: First: the animation is by design and resembles the animation in the Material Design guidelines. Second: you can just fork the project on Github if you really want to change this behaviour. I really don't see why you'd want to remove it - as mentioned, it is made like that by design.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I don't like the animation as it makes icons not align properly centered and I saw many people asking about this problem on the github page but on response so far. :(

Comment: But... it is by design. If you don't like it, you should fork the project and change it yourself. There's a reason roughike hasn't fixed this "issue". It's because it's not an issue - it's a matter of taste and I guess roughike has decided he doesn't want to add this customisation.
There's a method inside `BottomBarTab` called `void select(boolean animate)` that you could make public visible and use that when you select a tab for instance.

Comment: I'll definitely try that, Thank you but I checked the source code and to add the customizing option for this issue won't take so long for the author but you're right it's about taste I might need to edit the library or just find something different. Thanks....

Comment: You're absolutely right - and I think you're more than welcome to create a pull request on the project with your own changes. You'll make a lot of other people happy as well, if your PR is merged into the main project ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve some solution to this problem,I am also trying. I got some luck.May be you can try that
1. Please try to add this is in gradle file.
compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.4.0.1'

2. in your java code add the following:
       bottomBar.useFixedMode();

Comment: Hi Darshan, Thanks for your response. Actually you're talking about oldest version and I was using version 2. But anyways I got some reply from them but haven't tried yet as I shifted to something else. You may try to add this and let me know if it works.
bottomBar.setAnimation(null);
Thanks,
Robin